# Free products and direct products of abelian group $\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, abelian-groups

I want to know whether there is an embbeding (i.e. injection) from the free product $\mathbb{Z} \ast\mathbb{Z}$ into the direct product $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, and I believe there is no such embedding. Since by the universal property of  free products, $$\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z} \ast \mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}) = \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}) \times \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}). $$ Consider the canonical injection $i:\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$. Then the induced homomorphism $i^*:\mathbb{Z} \ast \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ which restricts to the two subgroup $\mathbb{Z}$ of $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ is just the inclusion $i$. But for instance, this would take the element $2^13^2$ and $1^13^21^1$ in $\mathbb{Z}\ast \mathbb{Z}$ (the exponent represents which group the letter is from) to $(2,3)\in \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$, which is clearly not injective.

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: If there were an embbeding $\mathbb{Z} \ast \mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, then $\mathbb{Z} \ast \mathbb{Z}$ would be abelian

Comment: @AlexL ah, yes I see!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the universal property of free products, there is a surjection from $\mathbb{Z\ast Z}$ to $S_3=\mathbb{Z_3\rtimes Z_2}$. Therefore, $\mathbb{Z\ast Z}$ is non-abelian.

As subgroups of abelian groups are abelian, this means that there is no injection $\mathbb{Z\ast Z}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{Z\times Z}$.